# extjs 4 - set horizontal scrolling to tbar in grid panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, horizontal-scrolling

I need to set horizontal scrolling to an ExtJS tbar which contains buttons in a row that are not visible in the end. Following is the code.

```
Ext.define('myProject.view.accounts.user.UserGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.usergrid',
    minHeight: 400,
    margin: '0,5,0,5',
    title: 'User Accounts',
    region: 'center',
    cls: 'grid-with-footer',
    scroll: 'vertical',        
    bind: {
        ...
    },
    initComponent: function() {
        ...
        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            columns: [{
                ...
            }],

            features: [{
                ...
            }],

            tbar: [{ // <-- this should be horizontally scrollable.
                ...
            }],

            bbar: {
                ...
            }
        });
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

(I'm using ExtJS 4.2.1)

Comment: Please give some fiddle for your issue to be solved]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using tbar, you can add it as a dockedItem, which allows for more configs

```
dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'top',
        overflowX: 'scroll', // <---- This allows horizontal scroll
        items: [
             .....
        ]
    }]
```

You can view this in a fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1t2l)

(edit: fiddle was in ExtJS 6.2 instead of 4.2, whoops)